# Confused about regular expression with negated words

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm playing around with Regular Expressions and this working assert doesn't make sense to me:

```
assert_equal " = ", "variable_1 = 42"[/\W+/]
```

In my mind, the answer should be `= 42`.

Doing `/\w+/` gives `variable_1`. You negate that, you're left with `= 42`. In a string of just `42`, doing `/w+/` doesn't remove it, so I don't see why it'd be removed from the string in my example.

EDIT: I don't want to confuse people. Doing `/\w+/` would also give `42` if it came first, and in my example of doing just `42`, it does in fact remove it.

The answer below links to here which helped:
http://rubular.com/

Comment: You may be thinking of "negated words" (really "characters") in the wrong way. `/\W+/` reads, "match as many consecutive characters as possible that are not the 'word' characters 'a-zA-Z0-9_'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `\W+` matches 1 or more non-word characters (other than `[A-Za-z0-9_]`), thus, the matched value is  `=` , not `= 42` (see [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ndvMlp)).

In your `assert_equal`, you do not replace, but *match* a single substring of non-word characters. See [this regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/jCLUwR2wjO).

See [`str[regexp]` reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html):

> If a Regexp is supplied, the **matching portion of the string is returned**.